# How can we cycle the serial number in Informix for column of type SERIAL?

Tags: informix

We are having an issue wherein our Informix DB serial number column, which is of type SERIAL is reaching the max limit.
We are re-setting it manually to "1" every time when we have this issue.

Is there a way to fix this using sequence/cycle without making any application changes?

We insert the data by giving the value as "0" and Informix automatically takes care of increment it.

Comment: What datatype are your application(s) using for the serial id? Also, the id can't be very important if you have to keep resetting the id values. "Theoretically" the id should never change, but you're changing it regularly, so what does that mean for your applications? Can you just drop the id column?

Comment: The field is of type "serial"

Comment: Yes but what application language type does do your applications read/write the ids from/to. eg is it Java and `Long` type, or C# `long` or python whatever ?

Comment: The language is C. But how does it matter?

Comment: Please answer the question... And what exact data type in C stores the ID? ie how many bytes for the type?

Comment: The C data type is "long" on a 64 bit unix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recycle a SERIAL column by inserting a row with an explicit number that is 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1), and then inserting another row with the number 0.  This will reset the counter back to 1, but subsequent attempts to insert a new serial number (with 0 as the inserted value) may collide with a pre-existing row, and the INSERT will then fail (but the next attempt will use the next serial number).

Example:

```
SQL[2416]: CREATE TABLE serial_wraparound
         > (
         >     number SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
         >     name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE
         > );
SQL[2417]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(0, "The first");
SQL[2418]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(0, "The second");
SQL[2419]: SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
SQL[2420]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(2147483647, "The last");
SQL[2421]: SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
2147483647|The last
SQL[2422]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(0, "Recycling");
SQL -268: Unique constraint (jleffler.u162_426) violated.
ISAM -100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
SQLSTATE: 23000 at /dev/stdin:8
SQL[2423]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(0, "Recycling");
SQL -268: Unique constraint (jleffler.u162_426) violated.
ISAM -100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
SQLSTATE: 23000 at /dev/stdin:9
SQL[2424]: INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, name) VALUES(0, "Recycling");
SQL[2425]: SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
2147483647|The last
3|Recycling
SQL[2426]:
```

Similar behaviour applies to SERIAL8 and BIGSERIAL columns, except that the wraparound value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (2<sup>63</sup>-1).  If you're repeatedly running out of your 2 billion serial numbers, maybe you should consider updating your application to use BIGSERIAL so you can use numbers up to 9 quintillion.  It's probably simpler in the long run.  (Do not use SERIAL8 (or INT8); I mentioned it for completeness.  New code should use BIGSERIAL and BIGINT.  Yes, there are reasons.)

(The command interpreter is my SQLCMD — available from the ESQL/C section of the Software Repository at the International Informix Users Group, the [IIUG](http://www.iiug.org/).)

You can also use ALTER TABLE to change the value in the column, but be aware that the primary key attribute gets lost if you don't respecify it in the ALTER TABLE.  This is a single sequence of statements (number 2455 if you're really curious):

```
+ DROP TABLE IF EXISTS serial_wraparound;
+ CREATE TABLE serial_wraparound (number SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
+ trace off;
+ INFO INDEXES FOR serial_wraparound 
P|jleffler|u171_494|jleffler| 171_494|number|||||||||||||||
U|jleffler|u171_495|jleffler| 171_495|name|||||||||||||||
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, NAME) VALUES(0, "The first");
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound(number, NAME) VALUES(0, "The second");
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
+ ALTER TABLE serial_wraparound MODIFY(number SERIAL(248761) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
+ trace off;
+ INFO INDEXES FOR serial_wraparound 
P|jleffler|u171_498|jleffler| 171_494|number|||||||||||||||
U|jleffler|u171_495|jleffler| 171_495|name|||||||||||||||
+ continue on;
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The modified");
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The petrified");
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
248761|The modified
248762|The petrified
+ ALTER TABLE serial_wraparound MODIFY(number SERIAL(2147483647) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
+ trace off;
+ INFO INDEXES FOR serial_wraparound 
P|jleffler|u171_500|jleffler| 171_494|number|||||||||||||||
U|jleffler|u171_495|jleffler| 171_495|name|||||||||||||||
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The inconsequential");
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The ungainly");
SQL -268: Unique constraint (jleffler.u171_500) violated.
ISAM -100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
SQLSTATE: 23000 at <<temp>>:27
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
248761|The modified
248762|The petrified
2147483647|The inconsequential
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The insubordinate");
SQL -268: Unique constraint (jleffler.u171_500) violated.
ISAM -100: ISAM error:  duplicate value for a record with unique key.
SQLSTATE: 23000 at <<temp>>:29
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
248761|The modified
248762|The petrified
2147483647|The inconsequential
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The piscatorial");
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
248761|The modified
248762|The petrified
2147483647|The inconsequential
3|The piscatorial
+ INSERT INTO serial_wraparound VALUES(0, "The equatorial");
+ SELECT * FROM serial_wraparound;
1|The first
2|The second
248761|The modified
248762|The petrified
2147483647|The inconsequential
3|The piscatorial
4|The equatorial
```

This shows that the ALTER TABLE can be used to set the next value — first using 248,761 (arbitrary, even if not random) and then 2,147,483,647 again.  You can't decrease the number, which is why you have to use the 2<sup>31</sup>-1 trick still.

The INFO INDEXES statements are there to ensure that the primary key constraint was preserved — some of the intermediate versions lost the primary key (uniqueness) constraint, giving different results from what I wanted.  The `trace on` (and `off`) commands turn command echoing off; you don't want to know the convolutions that INFO INDEXES goes through (or you can find out by getting SQLCMD for yourself if you do).  It is a statement managed by SQLCMD (and DB-Access); it is not understood by the Informix server per se.  It is similar to OUTPUT and LOAD and UNLOAD, etc, in this respect.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. The solution definitely fits for us and exactly what we are looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: I have a customer using an isql perform screen to add rows and he would like for the serial column to wraparound to 1000 after reaching 99999, but he will need to keep about the last 1,000 rows in the table to be able to query and update rows as customers will be making interest payments, redeeming their pawned items, or forfeit the pawns. The problem is, if we keep rows with serial id's 98000 to 99999, then the serial column will want to insert 100000 when the next row is added, so it looks I wont be able to grant customers wish unless I update serial id's 98000 to 99999 with negative values?

Comment: AFAIK, unless Perform is doing something unexpected, you should be able to cycle the SERIAL past 2^31-1 to 1, and then insert 999, and then the next number should be 1000, (or 9,999 and 10,000 if you want 5-digit numbers uniformly).  If you're using a reasonably modern version of Informix, you might even be able to create a trigger to do the cycling of the number.

Comment: Correction, 99000 to 99999.

Comment: As you might have already suspected, this is the only user I have running legacy SE 4.10 DOS version running in a VM, so triggers and SP's'are not supported. It takes about 12 years for the user to reach id 99,999 and local law requires keeping records for 5 years. The user wishes to use only up to 5 digits for querying and printing contracts and reports. I was just hoping there was some way to automate the wraparound, soon to happen, without having to manually reset it.

Comment: With SE 4.10 for DOS, the switch will need to be done manually.  This is what happens when you use software that's over 25 years old, though I know you're aware of that.

Comment: Agreed, this user started using the application in year 1991, and has said over the ages that it fulfills all his needs so well that he doesnt want to upgrade to newer versions, so my hourly rate periodically increases to support this legacy app. This will be the 2nd time I have manually wrapoed around the pawn contract i.d. number.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column type to `bigserial`, which is a 64-bit auto-increment type that will fit in the `long` datatype of your application without having to make changes.

As pointed out by `@JonathanLeffler`, if your applications retrieve the last serial generated, you'll have to change that code because the last added `bigserial` is retrieved in a different way.

Comment: Avoid SERIAL8; use BIGSERIAL instead.  One reason is that BIGSERIAL uses 8 bytes of storage where SERIAL8 uses 10 — I don't want to discuss why this is the case (hint: I've been annoyed about it for 20 years). Also, this doesn't quite fit with the 'no changes to the application' requirement. The main issue is that to retrieve the 'just created serial number', you have to make a function call with BIGSERIAL or SERIAL8, whereas you access part of the SQLCA with SERIAL — at least, in ESQL/C. The rules may be different for ODBC, JSBC — but at least the issue would have to be considered.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 2 extra bytes I can live with, but fine. bigserial it is. As for "no changes", it's not known if OP's code does this. Perhaps this minor change is worth not having to do the unscalable "hack" of the serial column. If the schema is busted because the column type is the wrong choice for the actual row volume, it's busted. There's no getting around fixing it IMHO.

Comment: I agree that a switch to 64-byte serial numbers is probably best — repeatedly dealing with recycling, especially given that insert operations will fail (unless there's some process that ensures that there are no really old record numbers in the table, so when the number recycles, there won't be collisions) is silly.  I also agree that without a lot more information about application (starting with 'language it is written in' and including 'API used to connect to the database') it is hard to know what the impact of the change might be — it might be a zero-change operation, it might not.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I filed for divorce from informix many years back when a server update changed the behaviour of adding a number of days to a date (I forget the which function/syntax) from returning a date to returning a timestamp! After the upgrade out entire (stored procedure based) server melted down and the company was off the air for a day while I rewrote every stored procedure to cater for this new behaviour. The change was irresponsible. After the clean up, I started the project to dump informix, and we moved to MySQL/Java (no stored procs) within a year or 2. I've never looked back.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leffler and Bohemian. Our thoughts are also same, to go with BIGSERIAL.